# binary counter in C

Tags: c, binary, counter

I am busy with a project where the following function needs to be implemented in C

```
void logic_circuit(int inputs[4],int outputs[2])
```

A counter needs to be created since all the 4 bit combinations needs to be inserted into this function...

```
void logic_circuit(int inputs[4],int outputs[2])
{
      //some calculations
      outputs[0] = ...
      outputs[1] = ...
}

//allocate memory
int inputs[4];
int outputs[2];

for(0000 to 1111)
{
     logic_circuit(0000,outputs);
}
```

I have been searching the web intensively but unfortunately I was'nt able to find anything usefull.Does anyone have an idea on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Why not use a bitmask? It would make it trivial to iterate through the combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of four nested loops, you could also fill the `inputs` array from a single loop counter,

```
for(mask = 0; mask < 0x10; ++mask) {
    for(index = 0; index < 4; ++index) {
        inputs[index] = (mask >> index) & 1;
    }
    logic_circuit(inputs, output);
}
```

That scales better to larger `inputs` arrays.

Comment: Where "larger" means up to the size in bits of whatever the type of `mask` is.

Comment: Right, but a 64-bit `mask` can keep you busy quite a while, I hope 128-bit integer types will be commonplace before that overflows ;)

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case, four nested `for` loops should work:

```
for (inputs[0] = 0; inputs[0] < 2; ++inputs[0]) {
  for (inputs[1] = 0; inputs[1] < 2; ++inputs[1]) {  
    for (inputs[2] = 0; inputs[2] < 2; ++inputs[2]) {
      for (inputs[3] = 0; inputs[3] < 2; ++inputs[3]) {
        logic_circuit(inputs, outputs);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gets very tiresome for larger inputs. A recursive approach scales better:

```
void enumerate_bits(int* bits, int n) {
  int bit;
  if (n == 0) {
    logic_circuit(bits, outputs);
  } else {
    for (bit = 0; bit < 2; ++bit) {
      bits[n-1] = bit;
      foo(bits, n-1);
    }
  }
}

enumerate_bits(inputs, 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply count from `0` to `15` and extract the bits into the array:

```
for (int i=0; i <= 15; i++) {
    inputs[0] = i & 0x1;
    inputs[1] = i & 0x2;
    inputs[2] = i & 0x4;
    inputs[3] = i & 0x8;
    logic_circuit(inputs, outputs);
}
```

Note that this doesn't put `0`s and `1`s into the array, but rather, `0`s or non-`0`s (e.g. for `15` it will put in `[1, 2, 4, 8]`).

Comment: Yes. but why write it in hex?

Comment: @JohanLundberg: for me, writing it in hex denotes "bit masking mode" and my brain switches accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Using bit masks is fine, but it's easy enough to use an array, and there's no limit to the size:

```
// produce next combination of inputs, returning false if it has cycled back to all off
bool increment(bool* ary, int len)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < len; i++ )
        if( (ary[i] = !ary[i]) )
            return true;

    return false;
}

void enumerate(void)
{
    bool inputs[4];
    memset(inputs, 0, sizeof inputs);

    // loop over all combinations of inputs
    do
    {
        logic_circuit(inputs, outputs);
    } while (increment(inputs, 4));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i < bitSize; i++){
    if(outputs[i]==1){        
        outputs[i] = 0;
        continue;
    }
    if(outputs[i]==0){ 
        outputs[i] = 1;
        logic_circuit(inputs, outputs);
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

if you don't want to use a bit array you could use bit masks like this

```
int mask = 1;
outputs[i] &= mask << i;
```

this will work with an array of bit of any size (or what ever width you chose to use for your int if you want to use the masking method)